# Value being overwritten through each loop iteration, even though the previous value isn't been referenced

Tags: c#, entity-framework, loops

I need a little help debugging a chunk of my code to Get Programs.

Here's the block:

```
    foreach (var job in socs)
    {
        string educationNeeded = "";
        string experienceNeeded = "";
        if (job.soc.EducationNeeded != null)
        {
            educationNeeded = job.soc.EducationNeeded.Education;
            experienceNeeded = job.soc.EducationNeeded.WorkExperience;
        }
        // For every onetsoc and every cipOnetSoc for each onetsoc, find the programs that apply and add them to the OccupationModel
        foreach (var onetSoc in job.soc.OnetSocs.ToList())
        {
            if (onetSoc != null)
            {
                var occupation = new OccupationModel()
                {
                    BrightFutureScore = new Random().Next(1, 100),
                    Description = onetSoc.Description,
                    PercentChange = job.percentChange,
                    EducationRequirement = educationNeeded,
                    ExperienceNeeded = experienceNeeded,
                    OpenPositions = job.averageAnnualOpenings ?? 0,
                    StartingSalary = job.annualWageMedian,
                    Name = onetSoc.Name,
                    OnetSoc = onetSoc.OnetSoc1
                };
                var cipOnetSocs = onetSoc.CipOnetSoc.ToList();
                if (cipOnetSocs.Count > 0)
                {
                    var cipOnetSocsCips = cipOnetSocs.Select(x => x.Cip6).ToList();
                    var programs = collegePrograms
                        .Where(x => cipOnetSocsCips.Contains(x.Cip))
                        .ToList();
                    foreach(var x in programs)
                    {
                        x.OnetSoc = onetSoc.OnetSoc1;
                    };
                    if (programs.Count > 0)
                    {
                        occupation.Programs = programs;
                    }
                }
                occupations.Add(occupation);
            }
        }

    }
```

If you look at the `foreach(var x in programs)` loop, what that's doing is setting the OnetSoc for every program in every onetsoc in every soc, if that makes sense. That's what the three loops do:

1. Loop through each soc
2. Loop through each OnetSoc on that soc and create the OccupationModel and get the Programs for the cipOnetSocs
3. Loop through each program, settings its OnetSoc value to the value from the 2nd level loop

The behavior I'm getting is that somehow, during debugging, the onetSoc is correct, but as  we loop through each soc, the onetSoc values of the previously added occupations change. 
Am I missing something in my loop that could be causing this?

Comment: Most likely your `ONetSocs` collection on each `job` is referencing some (all?) of the same objects rather than copies of the same objects.

Comment: @MattBurland  Hmmm, I suppose that's possible.  I'm getting the data via EF query, but I'm not selecting the OnetSocs into a new model or anything, so maybe i'll try that

Comment: Yes, it looks like you passing references and you expecting values... You should deep copy your objects when you passing it if that is  your intend. Because if you later change the underlying object that is referenced by onetSoc it will change everywhere, where it points to the same obejct in the memory. Also if you save your data through EF in x, you should save it as soon you assigned it, so it will have a hard copy in  DB. Although you still have to be careful with your object references if you use the same values later in your program, outside of this loop.
I hope it make sense.